# error: request for member ‘x’ in ‘y’, which is of non-class type ‘Class**’

Tags: c++, class, pointers

Im trying to create a game of "war" rigth now im just trying to get the deck setup, and im getting errors:

```
Running /home/ubuntu/workspace/Testing__.cc
/home/ubuntu/workspace/Testing__.cc: In function ‘void showName(Deck**)’:
/home/ubuntu/workspace/Testing__.cc:72:19: error: request for member ‘faceNum’ in ‘cards’, which is of non-class type ‘Deck**’
     int q = cards.faceNum;
                   ^
/home/ubuntu/workspace/Testing__.cc:73:22: error: request for member ‘suit’ in ‘cards’, which is of non-class type ‘Deck**’
     string s = cards.suit;
                      ^
/home/ubuntu/workspace/Testing__.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
/home/ubuntu/workspace/Testing__.cc:94:22: error: cannot convert ‘Deck*’ to ‘Deck**’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void makeDeck(Deck**)’
   makeDeck(&cards[52]);
                      ^
/home/ubuntu/workspace/Testing__.cc:102:27: error: cannot convert ‘Deck*’ to ‘Deck**’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void showName(Deck**)’
     showName(&cards[(r-1)]);
```

Here's the code as i have it so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib> //system("PAUSE");
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>    //NULL
#include <stdlib.h>   // srand, rand 
#include <ctime>     // time 
using namespace std;

class Deck
{
  public:
    int faceNum;
    string suit;

  friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Deck& cards);
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Deck& cards)
{
    os << cards.faceNum << " of " << cards.suit;
    return os;
}


void makeDeck(Deck *cards[52])
{
  //creates the deck, Ace -> King (1-13) of each suit
  int n=1;
  for (int x=0; x<13; x++)
  {
    cards[x]->faceNum = n;
    cards[x]->suit = "Spades";
    n++;
  }
  n=1;
  for (int x=13; x<26; x++)
  {
    cards[x]->faceNum = n;
    cards[x]->suit = "Clubs";
    n++;
  }
  n=1;
  for (int x=26; x<39; x++)
  {
    cards[x]->faceNum = n;
    cards[x]->suit = "Diamonds";
    n++;
  }
  n=1;
  for (int x=39; x<52; x++)
  {
    cards[x]->faceNum = n;
    cards[x]->suit = "Hearts";
    n++;
  }

}

/*
void selectCard()
{
  //each player will use this
}
*/

void showName(Deck *cards[52]) //displays name based on card.faceNum
{
  for(int c=0;c<52;c++)
  {
    int q = cards.faceNum; ///error here
    string s = cards.suit; ///error here
    if(q == 1)
      cout << "Ace of " << s;
    else if(q >= 2 && q <= 10)
      cout << q << " of " << s;
    else if(q == 11)
      cout << "Jack of " << s;
    else if(q == 12)
      cout << "Queen of " << s;
    else if(q == 13)
      cout << "King of " << s;
  }
}

int main()
{
  int r;
  int n=1;

  Deck cards[52];

  makeDeck(&cards[52]); ///error here

  //Show me "this" card.....
  do
  {
    cout << "(99 will exit)\nShow card (1-52): ";
    cin >> r;
    //cout << cards[(r-1)] << endl;
    showName(&cards[(r-1)]); ///error here

  }while (r != 99);


  //welcome!!
  //srand((unsigned)time(NULL)); //rand cast based on time



  //r = rand() % dtype + 1;

  //create deck

  //use selectCard() to randomly pull from pile
}
```

(Using Cloud9 (c9.io))
Its still early yet, so the whole program is incomplete, but i should be able to select a card (1-52) and have it display:

```
4 of Clubs
```

I've found (so far) from google searches is that there is an issue with my pointers... I think.... I had this all in the main() function and it worked, i split it into separate functions, minor code edits, and the errors appear.

I'm trying to wrap my head around pointers, so any help/advice would be greatly appreciated. I'm sure this is an easy 3 second answer, but I am truly stumped....

Thanks all!

Comment: Your function `makeDeck` shows that you know the proper syntax for accessing the `cards` array declared as `Deck *cards[52]`. Why do you suddenly switch to some completely different and nonsensical syntax in `showName`???

Comment: You should remove the complexities of passing an array and use `std::vector`.

Comment: They were similar, but i made those changes to get my errors smaller... and vectors have not been covered yet (doing an assignment out of a book, looking ahead they will make me change it to a vector looks like...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error messages are clear enough. For example in function showName parameter cards has type `Deck **` that is it is a pointer to pointer. Thus you may not use member access operator .

```
void showName(Deck *cards[52]) //displays name based on card.faceNum
{
  for(int c=0;c<52;c++)
  {
    int q = cards.faceNum; ///error here
    string s = cards.suit; ///error here
```

In function main you call function makeDeck supplying argument of type `Deck *` because `cards[52]` is an element of an array of type Deck with index 52 and expression &cards[52] is its address while function makeDeck has parameter of type `Deck **`

```
void makeDeck(Deck *cards[52])

//...

int main()
{
  int r;
  int n=1;

  Deck cards[52];

  makeDeck(&cards[52]); ///error here
```

So what you do is what you get.:)

Comment: so i fixed the showName(); error by: [int q = cards[r]->faceNum;] 
But isn't "makeDeck(&cards[52]);" passing the whole array?

Comment: @Gamer_Xolin_: No!  It is passing the address past the end of the array.  Element `cards[52]` does not exist, and is only good for iteration in the begin/end style.  `for( Deck *it = &cards[0], *end = &cards[52]; it < end; ++it )`

Comment: If you write `&cards` you will get a pointer to the entire array, its type is pointer-to-array, which means your function would need to be `makeDeck( Deck (*cards)[52] )` -- the parentheses are important.  And you would use it as `(*cards)[x].suit`.  This is ugly and therefore you should just call `makeDeck(cards)` and write the function as `makeDeck( Deck* cards )`, and use `cards[x].suit`

Comment: @Gamer_Xolin To pass the whole array you have to write  makeDeck( cards, 52 ); and function makeDeck has to be declared like makeDeck( Deck *, size_t n );